# Flexbox styling different in IE

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a basic button toolbar using `flexbox`. Everything looks exactly how I want it in all browsers except IE 11: https://jsfiddle.net/qoo5fmnv/1/

Am I doing something wrong here or is the styling I'm after not possible with IE flexbox?

Note by removing `flex-direction: column` from `flex-container a` everything looks as expected. Similarly by removing `flex: 1` from `flex-container span` and `flex-container section` everything looks fine. The combination of the two together seem to be messing things up.

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Added IE version above

Comment: The problem is with the `flex` property. See the duplicate.